# World to pixel transformation in Pyrender

Tags: computer-vision, transforms

I'm trying to transform a point in a 3D world rendered with pyrender to pixel coordinates. The world to camera frame transformation seems to work, however the camera to pixel frame transformation is incorrect and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate any hints!

The goal is to get the pixel coordinates uvw of the world-point UVW. Currently, I do the following:

### Create Camera:

I create a camera from an already existing intrinsic matrix (= K). I do this mainly for debugging purposes, so I can be sure that K is correct:

```
K = np.array([[415.69219382,   0.        , 320.        ],
   [  0.        , 415.69219382, 240.        ],
   [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]])
K = np.ascontiguousarray(K, dtype=np.float32)
p_cam = pyrender.camera.IntrinsicsCamera(fx = K[0][0], fy = [1][1], cx =[0][2],  cy = [1][2])

scene.add(p_cam, pose=cam_pose.get_transformation_matrix(x=6170., y=4210., z=60., yaw=20, pitch=0, roll=40)) # cam_pose is my own class
```

### Create transformation matrix

I'm creating an transformation matrix with an extrinsic rotation.

```
def get_transformation_matrix(self, x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll):
    from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
    '''
    yaw = rotate around z axis
    pitch = rotate around y axis
    roll = rotate around x axis
    '''
    xyz = np.array([
        [x],
        [y],
        [z]
    ])
    rot = rot_matrix = R.from_euler('zyx', [yaw, pitch, roll], degrees=True).as_matrix()
    last_row = np.array([[0,0,0,1]])
    tf_m = np.concatenate((np.concatenate((rot,xyz), axis = 1), last_row), axis = 0)
    return np.ascontiguousarray(tf_m, dtype=np.float32)
```

### Render image

Using the created camera, I render the following image. The point I'm trying to transform is the tip of the roof, which approximately has the pixel coordinates (500,160). I marked it in the 3D scene with the pink cylinder.

[image: Rendered image]

### Transform world to pixel frame

```
from icecream import ic
K = np.concatenate((K, [[0],[0],[0]]), axis = 1)
UVW1 = [[6184],[4245],[38],[1]] #the homogeneous coordinates of the pink cylinder in the world frame
world_to_camera = np.linalg.inv(cam_pose.transformation_matrix).astype('float32') @ UVW1
ic(world_to_camera)
camera_to_pixel = K @ world_to_camera
ic(camera_to_pixel/camera_to_pixel[2]) #Transforming the homogeneous coordinates back
```

**Output:**

```
ic| world_to_camera: array([[ 17.48892188],
                            [  7.11796755],
                            [-39.35071968],
                            [  1.        ]])

ic| camera_to_pixel/camera_to_pixel[2]: array([[135.25094424],
                                               [164.80738424],
                                               [  1.        ]])
```

### Results

To me, the world_to_camera pose seems like it might be correct (i might be wrong). However, when transforming from camera frame to pixel frame, the x-coordinate (135) is wrong (the y-coordinate (164) might still make sense).

Attached a screenshot of the 3D scene. The yellow cylinder+axes represent the camera, while the blue point represents the point I'm trying to transform (earlier pink in the rendered image).
[image: Screenshot of the 3D scene with camera and target point.]

So to me, the only source of error could be the intrinsic matrix, however I'm defining this matrix myself, so I don't see how it could be incorrect. Is there something I'm blind to?